# Unable to call function to class in different namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, phalcon

I have some functionality in namespace:

```
namespace LyteeAPI\Models\Order;
```

Now, I need to call SaveOrder() function, that resides in a controller in different namespace:

```
namespace Lytee\Library\Helpers\Backend
```

in controller Erp.

I need it to be a bit more dynamic, so I'm calling this controller like:

```
$erpApi = 'Lytee\Library\Helpers\Backend\\' . 'ErpApiClient';
            if( \class_exists($erpApi))
            {
                $erpApiClient = new $erpApi($erpConfig);
                $erpResult = $erpApiClient->saveOrder($this);
            }
```

$erpApiClient gets constructed, if I var_dump it, it has proper properties and functions (via get_class_functions()).

If I call

```
$erpApiClient->saveOrder($this)
```

without parameter $this, I get php error about missing arguments for this function, which tells me, that php knows which function to call.

But I never seems to reach inside of this function. Whatever I do in this saveOrder() function, it doesn't get executed..

Logs don't show any errors if function call is correct..

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you add a return type to `saveOrder`  what happens?

Comment: I had to move forward, so I was forced to do it differently, but thank you anyway for trying to analyze.